# my function that takes two strings as arguments as input, and finds its occurances in a string in python. the count is incorrect with several letters

Tags: python, function

Here is the what my function should do: take two strings as arguments(a string, and a letter, or letters) as input, and find the number of occurances of a letter or letters in a string. It has to be a function too. what am i doing wrong, it works correctly if I enter a letter, but if put multiple then the count is wrong?

****Expected input: "hello" "ll"
Expected output: 1
my output: 0****

```
def occurences(string1, string2):
    count = 0
    for word in string1:
     for character in word:
        count = count + 1
    return count
first_string = input('Enter the first string: ')
second_string = input('Enter the second string: ')
occurance_var = occurences(first_string,second_string)

print(second_string,'ocures', occurance_var,'in', first_string)
```

Comment: That doesn't return 0. But it doesn't return the number of occurrences of string2 in string1, either; currently it returns the length of `string1`, in your example `5`. Note the inner loop is always over one character.

Comment: I get the same result as @jonrsharpe; are you sure the posted code matches what you are running?

Comment: The function provided does not use string2, I don't how that could work even with a single letter. You want to make an if statement to compare each letter of string1 to the string2

Comment: ill try to give this a shot ty!

Answer (score 1):

@new_be_0905
you can use predefined string methods from python

you can do something like this

```
str1 = "Hello"
str2 = "ll"

print(str1.count(str2)) # Output: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not even use `string2` argument, so it is unclear to me how it *should* work.

If you just need the result -  find number of occurrences of substring in string, you can use `string.count(substring)`

If you want to understand how to implement this yourself - the approach that I would try is creating two variables - `count` and `substr_index`, then cycling through string and checking whether `char == substr[substr_index]`. If it is, add 1 to the `substr_index`. When the `substr_index==len(substr)`, reset the variable and add 1 to the `count`

Comment: im going to try this and redo my code! ty

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you do

```
for word in string1:
```

this loop is iterating over each character in string1, not each word. If you want to iterate over each word individually, you would need to split the string.

Second, you are never actually doing a comparison in your loop. Notice how you never call string2 anywhere in occurrences(). Your program as it is is simply counting each letter, so I am unsure how you are getting 0.

The easiest method of comparing for a string with length greater than 1 would be to slice the string, doing something like

```
string[i:i+2]
```